# display first result in included model, RoR3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

The following code displays all featured events, and all associated images of these, inside my view.
I'd like to know how I can display just the first image of each featured event.

```
# event model
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :start_date, :end_date, :content, :is_featured, :assets_attributes
  has_many :assets, :order => 'asset_order ASC'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true
end

# asset model
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :static
  has_attached_file :asset, :styles => { :large => "660x270#", :medium => "300x300#", :thumb => "100x100#" }
end

# event model
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title, :start_date, :end_date, :content, :is_featured,             :assets_attributes
    has_many :assets, :order => 'asset_order ASC'
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true
end

# static controller     
def show
    @events = Event.where(:is_featured => 1).includes(:assets)
    @static = Static.where(:id => params[:id]).first
    ...
end

# static show view
- @events.each do |event|
  - event.assets.each do |asset|
    =image_tag asset.asset.url(:medium)
  = event.title
  = event.start_date.to_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
# static show view
- @events.each_with_index do |event, index|
  - event.assets.each do |asset|
    =image_tag asset.asset.url(:medium) unless index > 0
  = event.title
  = event.start_date.to_date
```

Comment: That works, thanks, but my controller is grabbing all the images, when I only need one, the view seems like the wrong place to be doing this.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you want now.  However, keep in mind that your controller is actually only grabbing a reference to the associated Asset instance which includes a simple join on the DB side.  As long as you have your tables indexed properly the difference in overhead between what you are trying to do and this solution is going to be quite negligible and un-noticeable to the user, or on the heap. Otherwise you would pull the first Event with its Asset and then query the rest of the Events, excluding their Assets and the ID of the first Event.  Let me know if you need an example.